# How do I find the probability from a Markov Chain?

Tags: probability

Suppose that a Markov chain $\{X_n, n \geq 0\}$ has the following state space $I =
\{1, 2, 3\}.$ The probabilities for the initial state $X_0$ to be $1, 2$ and $3$ are $0.25, 0.5$
and $0.25,$ respectively.

If the current state is $1,$ the probabilities of moving to states $2$ and $3$ are $0.75$ and
$0,$ respectively.

If the current state is $2,$ the probabilities of moving to states $1$ and $3$ are $0.3$ and
$0.2,$ respectively.

If the current state is $3,$ the probabilities of moving to states $1$ and $2$ are $0$  and
$0.25,$ respectively.

Assuming a three state Markov chain,
calculate $P(X_0 = 1, X_1 = 2, X_2 = 1).$ Here $X_2$ is the state after one step
transition from $X_1,$ where $X_1$ is the state after one step transition from the
initial state $X_0.$

I have found the transition matrix, but we haven't learnt how to find probabilities from Markov chains, only how to find the transition matrix, the steady state and M^n as $n \to \infty.$ What do I do?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124769/discussion-on-question-by-adam-mac-how-do-i-find-the-probability-from-a-markov).

Answer (score 2):

One task is to find the product $p_0 \mathbf{P}^2,$ where
$p_0$ is the initial distribution and $\mathbf{P}^2$ is the two-step transition matrix. [Note that $\mathbf{P}^2 = \mathbf{P}\times\mathbf{P},$ where $\times$ denotes
matrix multiplication.]

Computation in R, where `%*%` is matrix multiplication.

```
P = matrix(c(.25, .75,  0,
              .3,  .5,  .2, 
               0, .25, .75), byrow=T, nrow=3)
     P
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 0.25 0.75 0.00
[2,] 0.30 0.50 0.20
[3,] 0.00 0.25 0.75


P2 = P %*% P;  P2      # 2-step transition matrix
       [,1]   [,2]   [,3]
[1,] 0.2875 0.5625 0.1500
[2,] 0.2250 0.5250 0.2500
[3,] 0.0750 0.3125 0.6125

p2 = p0 %*% P2;  p2   # step 2 dist'n  
[1,] 0.203125 0.48125 0.315625
```

Comment: Corrected typo just now.

Comment: I don't think that's what's wanted, because there is an intermediate state requirement in the middle. What is really desired is $(p_0 P)_2 P_{21}$.

Comment: @Ian, You're right this is a clue, not a complete answer. I did **not intend** to give camera ready copy for a complete solution, but to show a method that will be a useful start in the right direction. For that, showing, how to get one answer seems enough. // I've been teaching this stuff for about 60 years now. I'm giving the kind of help I might give if OP showed up at my office hours.

Comment: That's fair...still, considering their level of confusion, maybe you should spell out that it's a hint.

Comment: @Ian. OK. Modified first sentence in that direction.